# Moving slider with Cypress

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I've got a Slider component from rc-slider and I need Cypress to set the value of it.

```
<Slider
 min={5000}
 max={40000}
 step={500}
 value={this.state.input.amount}
 defaultValue={this.state.input.amount}
 className="sliderBorrow"
 onChange={(value) => this.updateInput("amount",value)} 
 data-cy={"input-slider"}
 />
```

This is my Cypress code:

```
it.only("Changing slider", () => {
    cy.visit("/");
    cy.get(".sliderBorrow")
      .invoke("val", 23000)
      .trigger("change")
      .click({ force: true })
  });
```

What I've tried so far does not work.
Starting point of slider is 20000, and after test runs it goes to 22000, no matter what value I pass, any number range.

Looks like it used to work before, [How do interact correctly with a range input (slider) in Cypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023428/how-do-interact-correctly-with-a-range-input-slider-in-cypress) but not anymore.

Comment: can you post the error screenshot as well.

Comment: The problem is that I am not getting an error, test is passing but the slider doesn't move, it stays where it is

Comment: Can you give this a try - `const nativeInputValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'value').set;
describe('Changing Slider', () => {
it('Updates the value and UI when changing a range input', () => {
cy.get('.sliderBorrow').then(($range) => {
const range = $range[0];
nativeInputValueSetter.call(range, 23000);
range.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {
value: 23000,
bubbles: true}));});});});`

Comment: Yeap, just opened that page on https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1570. 
Tried it and got this error now: Illegal invocation on this line ->> nativeInputValueSetter.call(range, 15000); 

Cypress doesn't like .call method

Comment: Yaa I saw that this solution got a lot of thumbs up, so I thought it might work for you as well.

Comment: Try adding should('have.value', 23000) at the end so it will run some assertion, before closing

Comment: I've added it but the value is still the same as it was with previous code. So the starting point is 20000, and after test runs it goes to 22000, no matter what value I pass, any number range

Comment: In my tests when I got such task I asked the development team to add buttons linked to key values on the slider and just doing click then checking the result.

Comment: I guess that nobody is able to help me

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is very and very simple. I found the solution coincidentally pressing enter key for my another test(date picker) and realized that pressing left or right arrow keys works for slider.
You can achieve the same result using props as well. The only thing you need to do is to add this dependency: cypress-react-selector and following instructions here: [cypress-react-selector](https://openbase.io/js/cypress-react-selector/documentation)

Example of using `{rightarrow}`

```js
it("using arrow keys", () => {
  cy.visit("localhost:3000");

  const currentValue  = 20000;
  const targetValue = 35000;
  const increment = 500;
  const steps = (targetValue - currentValue) / increment;
  const arrows = '{rightarrow}'.repeat(steps); 

  cy.get('.rc-slider-handle')
    .should('have.attr', 'aria-valuenow', 20000)
    .type(arrows)

  cy.get('.rc-slider-handle')
    .should('have.attr', 'aria-valuenow', 35000)

})
```

Comment: Time range is in days or weeks but step value in the input tag is in milliseconds. To move to an hour, it needs thousands of thousands of arrows to be typed. This makes the cypress crash. Any solution to fix this? May be like,  set the step attribute via cyrpess or jquery and then proceed

Answer (score 6):

@darkseid's answer helped guide me reach an optimal solution.

There are two steps

1. Click the slider's circle, to move the current focus on the slider.
2. Press the keyboard arrow buttons to reach your desired value.

My slider jumps between values on the sliders, therefore this method would work. (I am using Ion range slider)

This method doesn't require any additional depedency.

[image: slider image]

```
// Move the focus to slider, by clicking on the slider's circle element
cy.get(".irs-handle.single").click({ multiple: true, force: true });
// Press right arrow two times
cy.get(".irs-handle.single").type(
  "{rightarrow}{rightarrow}"
);
```

Comment: I think `rightArrow` is camel case https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type#Arguments

Answer (score 3):

**For whoever comes across this with Material UI/MUI 5+ Sliders:**

First off, this github issue and comment might be useful: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1570#issuecomment-606445818.
I tried changing the value by accessing the input with type range that is used underneath in the slider, but for me that did not do the trick.

My solution with MUI 5+ Slider:

```
<Slider
  disabled={false}
  step={5}
  marks
  data-cy="control-percentage"
  name="control-percentage"
  defaultValue={0}
  onChange={(event, newValue) =>
    //Handle change
  }
/>
```

What is important here is the **enabled marks property**. This allowed me to just click straight on the marks in the cypress test, which of course can also be abstracted to a support function.

```
cy.get('[data-cy=control-percentage]').within(() => {
  // index 11 represents 55 in this case, depending on your step setting.
  cy.get('span[data-index=11]').click();
});
```

Comment: This within + data-index pattern worked great.  I had to do:
`cy.get("span[data-index=0]").click({ multiple: true });` for the 0th index in my case...

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to tackle this using [Application actions](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/01/03/stop-using-page-objects-and-start-using-app-actions/), provided you are able to modify the app source code slightly.

Application actions give the test a hook into the app that can be used to modify the internal state of the app.

I tested it with a Function component exposing `setValue` from the `useState()` hook.
You have used a Class component, so I guess you would expose `this.updateInput()` instead, something like

```
  if (window.Cypress) {
    window.app = { updateInput: this.updateInput };
  }
```

**App: index.js**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

import Slider from 'rc-slider';
import 'rc-slider/assets/index.css';

function App() {

  const [value, setValue] = useState(20000);

  // Expose the setValue() method so that Cypress can set the app state
  if (window.Cypress) {
    window.app = { setValue };
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Slider
        min={5000}
        max={40000}
        step={500}
        value={value}
        defaultValue={value}
        className="sliderBorrow"
        onChange={val => setValue(val)}
        data-cy={"input-slider"}
      />
      <div style={{ marginTop: 40 }}><b>Selected Value: </b>{value}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Test: slider.spec.js**

The easiest way I found assert the value in the test is to use the `aria-valuenow` attribute of the slider handle, but you may have another way of testing that the value has visibly changed on the page.

```js
describe('Slider', () => {

  it("Changing slider", () => {
    cy.visit("localhost:3000");

    cy.get('.rc-slider-handle')
      .should('have.attr', 'aria-valuenow', 20000)

    cy.window().then(win => {
      win.app.setValue(35000);
    })

    cy.get('.rc-slider-handle')
      .should('have.attr', 'aria-valuenow', 35000)

  })
})
```

Comment: Is it confirmed it works? Because this is a major issue for many people and would be nice.

Comment: @RosenMihaylov yes, but be aware that it's not 100% foolproof, for instance the change handler `onChange={val => setValue(val)}` is not regression tested by this method. The only way to do that with the rc-slider component is (maybe) to use mousedown and mousemove events.

Comment: @RosenMihaylov have a look my solution below

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work with the popular react-easy-swipe:

```
cy.get('[data-cy=week-picker-swipe-container]')
  .trigger('touchstart', {
    touches: [{ pageY: 0, pageX: 0 }]
  })
  .trigger('touchmove', {
    touches: [{ pageY: 0, pageX: -30 }]
  })
```