# In Cypress, how to move a slider?

Tags: cypress

I have just started exploring Cypress and came across such a problem:

**Is it possible to select/ set a value in a slider component?**

For example lets take this simple piece of code

```html
<div class="col-10 projection_percentile_slider form-group"><label for="cc_7of9b5za1" class=""></label>
    <div class="ccr-slider form-control ccr-marks-below ccr-tick-marks">
        <div class="rc-slider rc-slider-with-marks">
            <div class="rc-slider-rail"></div>
            <div class="rc-slider-track" style="left: 0%; right: auto; width: 26.5306%;"></div>
            <div class="rc-slider-step"><span class="rc-slider-dot rc-slider-dot-active" style="display: none; left: 0%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot rc-slider-dot-active" style="display: none; left: 1.02041%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot rc-slider-dot-active" style="display: none; left: 2.04082%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot rc-slider-dot-active" style="display: none; left: 3.06122%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot rc-slider-dot-active" style="display: none; left: 4.08163%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot rc-slider-dot-active" style="display: none; left: 5.10204%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot rc-slider-dot-active" style="display: none; left: 6.12245%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot rc-slider-dot-active" style="display: none; left: 7.14286%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot rc-slider-dot-active" style="display: none; left: 8.16327%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot rc-slider-dot-active" style="display: none; left: 9.18367%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot rc-slider-dot-active" style="display: none; left: 10.2041%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot rc-slider-dot-active" style="display: none; left: 11.2245%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot rc-slider-dot-active" style="display: none; left: 12.2449%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot rc-slider-dot-active" style="display: none; left: 13.2653%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot rc-slider-dot-active" style="display: none; left: 14.2857%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot rc-slider-dot-active" style="display: none; left: 15.3061%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot rc-slider-dot-active" style="display: none; left: 16.3265%;"></span>
            .........
            none; left: 82.6531%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot" style="display: none; left: 83.6735%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot" style="display: none; left: 84.6939%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot" style="display: none; left: 85.7143%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot" style="display: none; left: 86.7347%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot" style="display: none; left: 87.7551%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot" style="display: none; left: 88.7755%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot" style="display: none; left: 89.7959%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot" style="display: none; left: 90.8163%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot" style="display: none; left: 91.8367%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot" style="display: none; left: 92.8571%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot" style="display: none; left: 93.8776%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot" style="display: none; left: 94.898%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot" style="display: none; left: 95.9184%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot" style="display: none; left: 96.9388%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot" style="display: none; left: 97.9592%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot" style="display: none; left: 98.9796%;"></span><span class="rc-slider-dot" style="display: none; left: 100%;"></span></div>
            <div tabindex="0" class="rc-slider-handle" role="slider" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuemax="99" aria-valuenow="27" aria-disabled="false" style="left: 26.5306%; right: auto; transform: translateX(-50%);"></div>
            <div class="rc-slider-mark"><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 0%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 1.02041%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 2.04082%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 3.06122%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 4.08163%;">
                    <div class="ccr-mark-with-number">
                        <div class="ccr-slider-tick-label">5</div>
                    </div>
                </span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 5.10204%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 6.12245%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 7.14286%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 8.16327%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 9.18367%;">
                    <div class="ccr-mark-with-number">
                        <div class="ccr-slider-tick-label">10</div>
                    </div>
                </span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 10.2041%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 11.2245%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 12.2449%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 13.2653%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 14.2857%;">
                    <div class="ccr-mark-with-number">
                        <div class="ccr-slider-tick-label">15</div>
                    </div>
                </span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 15.3061%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 16.3265%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 17.3469%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 18.3673%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 19.3878%;">
                    <div class="ccr-mark-with-number">
                        <div class="ccr-slider-tick-label">20</div>
                    </div>
                </span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 20.4082%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 21.4286%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 22.449%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 23.4694%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 24.4898%;">
                    <div class="ccr-mark-with-number">
                        <div class="ccr-slider-tick-label">25</div>
                    </div>
                </span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 25.5102%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text rc-slider-mark-text-active" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 26.5306%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 27.551%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 28.5714%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 29.5918%;">
                    <div class="ccr-mark-with-number">
                        <div class="ccr-slider-tick-label">30</div>
                    </div>
                .......
                .......
                    <div class="ccr-mark-with-number">
                        <div class="ccr-slider-tick-label">85</div>
                    </div>
                </span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 86.7347%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 87.7551%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 88.7755%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 89.7959%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 90.8163%;">
                    <div class="ccr-mark-with-number">
                        <div class="ccr-slider-tick-label">90</div>
                    </div>
                </span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 91.8367%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 92.8571%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 93.8776%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 94.898%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 95.9184%;">
                    <div class="ccr-mark-with-number">
                        <div class="ccr-slider-tick-label">95</div>
                    </div>
                </span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 96.9388%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 97.9592%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 98.9796%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span><span class="rc-slider-mark-text" style="transform: translateX(-50%); left: 100%;"><span class="ccr-tick-mark"></span></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is what I have tried, but the value doesn't change:

```javascript
cy.get('.rc-slider-handle').eq(0).invoke('attr', 'aria-valuenow', '20')
cy.get('.rc-slider-handle').eq(1).invoke('attr', 'aria-valuenow', 30)
```

Here are the pictures of the output:

[image: Slider widgets]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving slider with Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64855669/moving-slider-with-cypress)

Comment: sorry i think skkreea answer is more clean , but thanks for suggesting this. And I would prefer it to open.

Comment: IMO the linked answer is more complete and says the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dragging itself doesnt work as far as i know, you can use the arrowkeys like this

```
// Move the focus to slider, by clicking on the slider's circle element
cy.get(selector).click({ multiple: true, force: true });
// Press right arrow two times
cy.get(selector).type(
  "{rightarrow}{rightarrow}"
);
```